# Is it possible to restore contacts from a few days back

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts, restore

I honestly don't know what happened, but it appears that I lost a number of key contacts out of my address book. I didn't delete them manually, but regardless of what the cause was - they are gone.

Is it possible to restore contacts back, say from a few days ago?

Additionally, and this might be symptomatic of a bigger issues, some of my contacts appear in duplicate.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Disconnect all iCloud devices from the network (in case one is problematic)
2. Log in to iCloud.com from a computer
3. Select Settings web app
4. Scroll to the bottom left
5. Select Restore Contacts
   [image]
6. See what archives exist and then go to the contacts web app to make sure the cloud version of contacts is wrong.
7. Optionally, export all the current contacts in case a restore makes things worse

Comment: This worked. I love you!

Comment: Love you right back! @Jam